# Postive or negative null check in if-statement

Tags: if-statement, null, nested-loops

I do a lot of null checking in my code, and usually I will check for not null before going on to my for or more if/else statements.

For example:

```
if(x!=null) {
     for(int y:x) {
         if(y.property1 != null) {
             if( y.property < n) {
             }
         } else {
         }
     }
}
```

Is the following better practice?

```
 if(x ==null) {
     //exit or w/e you want to do
 }
 for(int y:x) {
      if(y ==null){
      }
      if(y<0) {
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they are the same to the engine, doesn't make any difference to the engine. It depends on your logic, but here, it's the same, dude

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any difference... Equal / Negate Equal execute same instruction cycle.

But its always a good practice to check for all required data before manipulating any calculation

Answer (score 0):

These achieve the same end. It would be up to your personal preference.